# How to parse filter clause in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I parse clauses, given as parameters in a ***filter*** method?

Running of

> filters_clause = Record.start>='2017-07-17'
>
> print(filters_clause)

gives a string

> records.start >= :start_1

It's necessary a real value instead of *:start_1* and that value must have been passed by *process_bind_param* function. Which method I have to use to get a string like that: *records.start >= '1500321600.0'*?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8

from __future__ import ( division, absolute_import,
                         print_function, unicode_literals )

import time

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, attributes
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, Integer, String


Base = declarative_base()


class EpochTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = Integer

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            if value.isdigit():
                return value

            if len(value) == 10:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d"))
            elif len(value) == 13:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H"))
            elif len(value) == 16:
                value = time.mktime(time.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))

        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(value))


class Record(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    start = Column(EpochTime)


engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
session.configure(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

record = Record(name = 'Record 1', start = '2017-07-16')
session.add(record)
record = Record(name = 'Record 2', start = '2017-07-17')
session.add(record)
record = Record(name = 'Record 3', start = '2017-07-18')
session.add(record)

session.commit()


filters_clause = Record.start>='2017-07-17'
s = session.query(Record).filter(filters_clause)
res = s.all()
names = [i.name for i in Record.__table__.c]
rows = [[row.__dict__.get(i) for i in names] for row in res]

for row in rows:
    print(row)

print(0, s)
print(1, filters_clause)
```

Comment: You're asking a different question in your title ("parsing") than in the body ("compiling to `records.start >= '1500321600.0'`"). Can you clarify your question?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue, please excuse any errors on my part. I thought that the 'compile' method is one what I looking for. But using of that method didn't give me expected result. However maybe I did something wrong. Anyway I think that your remark is accurate and just 'compiling' of clause values required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is [`literal_binds`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined):

```
print(filters_clause.compile(engine, compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))
# records.start >= 1500274800.0
```

Be wary of SQL injection if you use `literal_binds`, though.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I want! I guessed it must be easy but couldn't find a solution ))

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can achieve this simply with vanilla sqlalchemy.
You can try using a custom function, like:

```
import re

def represent_filter(expression):
    expression = expression.compile()
    params = expression.params
    prefixed_names = [':' + param for param in params]
    pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(prefixed_names))

    def substitute_param_value(match):
        return params[match.group()[1:]]

    return pattern.sub(substitute_param_value, expression.string)
```

Then use it calling `represent_filter(filters_clause)` and it will return `records.start >= 2017-07-17`.

You could force *represent_filter* function to quote substituted value, using  something like `repr(str(params[match.group()[1:]]))` instead of `params[match.group()[1:]]`.

An other approach would be to traverse given expression (in your case `filters_clause` is a `BinaryExpression`, there are unary expressions too), check left and right sides and build your own representation. If you only want to recover the value (the date which you provided to filter) it is in `filters_clause.right.effective_value`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's no question to get records.start >= '2017-07-17'. It's easy. There is a question to compile value '2017-07-17' into '1500321600.0' by process_bind_param method created especially for custom types of SA. That method called automatically when we perform session.query(Record).filter(filters_clause) and I don't know how I can call that method just for one argument (start) without performing a whole query.